# sweetalert pop ups every page loaded when flash message not set in php 8.0

Tags: php, codeigniter, sweetalert

I switched to php 8.0 because I had error `unexpected character in input: ' filename lib/rules.php`, but in php 8.0 I face another problem that sweetalert always pop ups in every pages that loaded without the trigger like login success, maybe the problem is the session flash message is error because deprecated CI 3, any idea how to overcome this?

edit: when I go deeper I found that the same flash message is pop ups in every pages I load, and will not change until new flash message is set

when I switched to php 7.4 it comes back to normal but yeah, the first problem is there again